# PhoneGap doesn't find table in android-database

Tags: android, cordova

Inside my activity that loads the web-view I successfully created a db with a table.

```
DB-Name: OpenDb
Table  : filePath
Version: 1
```

I also got some Test-Values inside, I can read from my activity/helper-class:

```
id=1, path=/external/images/media/3535
```

Inside the web-view I try to access the data from the table:

```
dbHandler.getData = function() {
     var db = window.openDatabase("OpenDb", "1", "OpenDatabase", 200000);
     db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}
function queryDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM filePath', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
 }
```

Here's the error:

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: filePath
```

How come?

Comment: did u create the table?

Comment: Yes I did, I can request values from it's table out of the activity

Comment: how can u get db values out of the activity?

Comment: did u mean to say u checkd in chrome?

Comment: no, I printed the table-content to the logcat

Comment: I think you are printing native application's database and not the browser's database..u need to check it in chrome if you have table in your database...

Comment: when i receive a data by an intent, I put those data into the database, to recall them from the web-view. After that i print the entire content of the table out to the logcat. to check if everything is correct

Comment: Ok, so phonegap doesn't refer to the same database my activity does?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39925/discussion-between-vicky-gonsalves-and-marcel)

Comment: Ok, it unfortunately doesn't work. The activity and phonegap don't use the same database. They have to be linked by a phonegap-plugin.

Comment: Now I have to share date over a local file .. uargh :P